# Simulate time series satisfying a covariance matrix

Tags: python, random, correlation

How can I generate a df with random values having same covariance and mean as my input df?

I have an input dataframe: "my_input_df" with size= (240, 8)
    I  want an output dataframe "my_output_df" with size  (10,000 , 8), where 
    each of the 10,000 rows is a random draw of the corresponding column such 
    that cov and mean of "my_output_df" are the same as covariance and mean of 
    "my_input_df".

That is:

```
my_input_df:

A       B      C       D
a1      b1     c1     d1
a2      b2     c2     d2
a3      b3     c3     d3
....
a240   b240    c240   d240

my_output_df:
A              B             C               D
rand_a1       rand_b1        rand_c1         rand_d1
rand_a2       rand_b2        rand_c2         rand_d2
rand_a3       rand_b3        rand_c3         rand_d3
... 
rand_a10000   rand_b10000    rand_c10000     rand_d10000
```

My_ouput_df must have random values for each column, satisfying:

```
my_output_df.cov() = my_input_df.cov()
```

And:

```
mean of my_output_df['A'] = mean of my_input_df['A']
mean of my_output_df['B'] = mean of my_input_df['B']
mean of my_output_df['C'] = mean of my_input_df['C']
.... Etc
```

I suspect it is related to numpy.random.multivariate_normal, but it is not 
    clear to me how to use it in dataframes.

Comment: Look into Cholesky decomposition. This isn't a python question yet -- still statistics.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to put it in Python, that is exactly my question!  Can numpy.random.multivariate_normal be used for dataframes?

Comment: You can easily conver dataframes to numpy arrays. Would this function solve your problem ?

Comment: Please check this documentation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all.
The answer is simple:

Use np.random.multivariate_normal and convert to df, as below:

```
dataNew = np.random.multivariate_normal(my_mean,cov,1000)
where  my_mean=my_input_df.mean  
and    cov = my_input_df.cov()
```

To convert to df the result of multivariate_normal use

```
my_output_df = pd.DataFrame(dataNew , columns= 'A', 'B', 'C'...)
```

This works.
Thanks again.